# Gnome login screen only displays on LED TV

Tags: 20.04, multiple-monitors, display, gdm

I have an issue were when I boot up or logout the default gnome login screen will only display on my LED TV (which is normally off) connected to my graphics card. How do i ensure that the login screen display on my primary display (24 inch monitor)?

I have two screens setup as follows:

A 24 inch LG monitor connected to graphics card via display port
A 58 inch Samsumg LED TV connected to graphics card via HDMI

Graphics card: AMD Radeon RX Vega 54

During boot up and logout the primary display (LG monitor) will only show a purple screen, while the LED TV will display the GNOME login screen with password field and user image. In the GNOME display settings the single display setting is selected and set to the LG monitor. I have tried to set screens to join display and mirror, both offer no solutions. I have attempted to copy the file `~/.config/monitors.xml` into `~gdm/.config/` as suggested by other posts, but this also does not solve the problem. Also when in Gnome display settings, the LG monitor is identified as 2, and the LED TV is indentified as 1.

Are there any other solutions that I can try?

Comment: From memory... Display settings panel, in a two display, extend setup, if you option-drag the top panel from one monitor to the other monitor, you define which one is the primary monitor. Report back.

Comment: Thank you. I did this, and set my LG monitor as primary display. However, it did not solve the problem. Maybe this might help: on boot-up, the motherboard load screen and grub menu all display on the monitor. Once you get to the gdm login screen, it switches the TV, and when done logging in it switches back to the monitor.

Comment: Sorry, no further ideas then.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, what helped is:

1. Set your monitors the way you want in: Settings->Displays
2. Save it
3. Copy your monitors.xml from `~/.config/monitors.xml`
4. Paste it to `/var/lib/gdm3/.config/`
5. In `/etc/gdm3/custom.conf` changing from `#WaylandEnable = false` to `WaylandEnable = false`
6. Restart

Step 5 is enabling the usage of Xorg.

This might help:

```
cp ~/.config/monitors.xml /var/lib/gdm3/.config
```